# Batch file to copy the first PDF in multiple folders from c:\pdf\ to single folder c:\qa\

Tags: batch-file, pdf, automation

I  have hundreds of sub folders coming off a c:\pdf\ folder.

I want to take the first pdf (sorted by name) in each sub folder and copy them to a single folder, say c:\QA\ so I can check the PDF for errors manually.

Can anyone help? Please!

I have this so far:

```
@echo off
cls
cd c:
cd c:\pdf\
for /r %%a in (*.pdf) do (
    copy %%a c:\qa\%%~nxa
    GOTO :EXIT
)
:Exit
```

Note File names are unique. Target dir is never a subdir of source. The baove code works for the first pdf in a sub folder but does not do the rest of the sub folders.

Comment: We'd be happy to help, when you've created a batch file, tried it and posted it here with an explanation of where you are struggling with it.

Comment: Compo, thanks for the comment.I'm struggling as I don't program for a living unfortunately. my knowledge of batch files is limited to renaming and copying a certain file for a to b, but not using loops or such like. Sorry i cant provide the basics!

Comment: That's not valid code, also please **edit** your original post with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code for you. It looks inside each directory and any potential subdirectory below `C:\PDF`, it does not look at files inside `C:\PDF`. If you're looking for something different then update your question accordingly.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /D /R "C:\PDF" %%A In (*) Do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Dir/B/A-D/O-N "%%A\*.pdf" 2^>Nul') Do (
        Set "first=%%A\%%B")
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Exist "!first!" Copy "!first!" "C:\QA"
    EndLocal)
Pause
```

*Please don't just use it, take your time to learn it by checking various references as well*.

Answer (score 0):

The New Technology File System (NTFS) returns a list of file names matching a wildcard pattern always sorted in alphabetical order. So for NTFS formatted partitions the following batch code is perhaps enough for this task.

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in ("C:\pdf\*") do if exist "%%D\*.pdf" call :CopyFirstFile "%%D"
goto :EOF

:CopyFirstFile
for %%F in ("%~1\*.pdf") do (
    copy "%%F" C:\qa\
    goto :EOF
)
goto :EOF
```

Please note that first **FOR** ignores subfolders with hidden attribute set. And the second **FOR** in subroutine `CopyFirstFile` ignores PDF files with hidden attribute set.

Another solution working also for File Allocation Table (FAT) partitions (FAT16, FAT32, exFAT) uses the command **DIR** to get the list of *.pdf files sorted by name.

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in ("C:\pdf\*") do if exist "%%D\*.pdf" call :CopyFirstFile "%%D"
goto :EOF

:CopyFirstFile
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /A-D /B /ON "%~1\*.pdf"') do (
    copy "%~1\%%F" C:\qa\
    goto :EOF
)
goto :EOF
```

The command **DIR** ignores directories matching the pattern *.pdf and finds also hidden *.pdf files because of option `/A-D`. But **COPY** does not copy a hidden *.pdf file!

It would be perhaps better to use **MOVE** instead of **COPY** as on next run the batch file would copy the same files again if the folders in `C:\pdf` are not modified in the meantime.

The command lines below label `CopyFirstFile` are interpreted as subroutine called by the first **FOR** loop.

The first `goto :EOF` exits batch file processing once the first **FOR** loop iterating over all non hidden subdirectories of `C:\pdf` finished.

The second `goto :EOF` exits the second **FOR** loop and the subroutine after copying the first file found in the directory passed as first (and only) argument to the subroutine.

The third `goto :EOF` would not be really necessary as this command line should be never executed and is additionally also not needed when there are no more command lines in the batch file. But it is good practice to make sure that each block called as subroutine has as last line `goto :EOF` or alternatively `exit /B` which is exactly the same as `goto :EOF`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to combine the features of **Dir & For** . Now, You can simply analyze the code and modify it according to your need.

***Hint for the Code:***

```
CD /D "C:\PDF"
DIR /s /b *.pdf >a.txt
For /f "Tokens=*" %%A In (a.txt) Do (Copy /Y "%%A" "C:\QA")
Exit
```

And, it is almost all you need. :)